# How to read the unit price of an Item with IPP DevKit

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I've seen elsewhere how to set the UnitPrice on an Item, using the wiley and elusive Item1 field as Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Money. But how do I READ the unit price from the Item1 field? I can't cast it. The new operator doesn't work ("new ...Money(myItem.Item1)"). So how do I get the price?

I realize the DevKit will probably never be changed so this makes sense. But can we at least get some doc explaining all those strange "xxxItemxxx" fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, realmId, intuitServiceType);
DataServices commonService = new DataServices(context);

```
                        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item qbdItem = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item();
                        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Money unitPrice = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Money();
                        unitPrice.Amount = 22;
                        unitPrice.AmountSpecified = true;
                        qbdItem.Item1 = unitPrice;
                        IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item> qbdItemsResult = commonService.FindAll(qbdItem, 1, 10) as IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item>;
                        foreach (var itemResult in qbdItemsResult)
                        {
                            Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Money test1UnitPrice = itemResult.Item1 as Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Money;
                        }
```

You can use the above code for .Net.

Comment: This would work really well if Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item had a UnitPrice property. But it doesn't :-(

Comment: You and I must be looking at different versions of the .NET DevKit. I pasted your code into my solution, and it simply does not recognize the UnitPrice property of IPP.Data.Qbd.Item. I verified that I have the latest version of Intuit.Ipp.Data.dll (2.1.12.0) but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated my answer for 2.1.12.0 version. See the code above.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Response XML of Item entity suggests that 'UntiPrice' is a top level tag.

I tried this usecase using java. PFB code.

```
    QBItemService itemService = QBServiceFactory.getService(context,QBItemService.class);
    items = itemService.findAll(context,1, 100);
    for (QBItem item : items) {
        System.out.println("Name - " + item.getName() + " UnitPrice - " + item.getUnitPrice().getAmount());
```

Can you please try the same in .Net and let me know if it works in the same way.

Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Money [ getAmount() ]

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Between this and Nimisha's answer I should be able to get it working.

Comment: Where does your "getUnitPrice()" come from? Because I'm not seeing it in the .NET DevKit.

Comment: In java, item has that getter method ( getUnitPrice ). It returns Money object. Not sure how it works in .net. I'll try this .net and share if I find something.